# What does it do if I choose "None" in Hardware Accelerator?

Tags: google-colaboratory

Pretty straightforward question. I was just wondering what was doing the calculus when this option was chosen. Does it run on Goolge's CPU or on my hardware ?

I have looked on Google, Stackoverflow and Colab's Help without success finding a precise answer

Thanks :)

PS : When running a full Dense Network "without" accelarator it is approx. as fast as with TPU and a lot faster than with GPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your guess is correct: None means CPU only, but on a Colab-managed cloud VM rather than your local machine. (Unless you've connected to a [local Jupyter instance](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html).

Also keep in mind that you'll need to adjust your code in order to take advantage of hardware accelerators like GPUs and TPUs.

Speedup on a GPU is often a bit magical since many frameworks automatically detect and take advantage of GPUs. Built-in support for TPUs is rare, and obtaining a speedup from TPUs will require adjusting your code.

Comment: Well thanks for your answer man :).  

However since you are talking about that : as I said with my dense network the CPU and TPU worked a lot better than the GPU, contrary to what you said and what I thought too. Is this the expected behavior for a Dense NN ? For reference, the one I made was an extremely simple keras Sequential model on tensorflow with some Dense layers for Image training (MNIST).